# Unable to MSBUILD Multiple 'Target' parameters in Parallel

Tags: c#, msbuild

When executing the solution build as follows, multiple worker nodes are created and the process finishes in 2 mins.

> MSBuild.exe path\to.sln /p:OutDir=C:\out\ -m:4 /p:Configuration=QA /p:Platform="Any CPU"

However, when attempting to execute the SLN with specific targets (T1,T2,T3), these are built in **series** rather than **parallel**. Only the main msbuild.exe node is created; no workers

> MSBuild.exe -target:Deployment\T1 -target:Deployment\T2 -target:Deployment\T3 
>    path\to.sln /p:OutDir=C:\out\ -m:6 /p:Configuration=QA /p:Platform="Any CPU"

Despite the -m:6 parameter, only a single worker node is created; the process takes 2.5* longer to do the same thing.

- Is there some limitation when specifying targets that prevent them being executed in parallel?
- Any workarounds?

Comment: I didn't know of a limitation. But why are you specifying the Deployment\T1 target twice?

Comment: Whoops - copy/paste issue. In my actual command those are project names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to my understanding, parallel msbuild is only for "msbuild core tasks". I mean, there is an msbuild basic tasks: restore, build, test etc', and these tasks can run parallel.

But msbuild not try to parallel the targets. In this case, msbuild will run them sequencely.

The targets do for cases like `/t:Restore,Build,Test`, And it will never happen in parallel.

So, you can say this is limitation.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I feared. In the end (for anyone else looking for the solution) I just kicked off 6x simultaneous MSBUILD jobs, 1x per target, which ran in a total of a minute and a half! Fastest way possible.